# Pause music when phone receives any incoming calls, home button is pressed and when phone screen goes off(lockscreen)

Tags: java, android

while playing music using this mediaplayer, whenever a call comes, home button is pressed and lockscreen appears and on return to the app after the above problems...the play button in the app doesnt respond....I want to pause the music untill I return to the app and should continue playing from where it had stopped......plz help...

ekdanta.java

```js
public class ekdanta extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable,View.OnClickListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    TextView tv4;
    Button b9, b10,but19;
    int count = 0;
    MediaPlayer play;
    SeekBar seek_bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ekdanta);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    tv4.setTextSize((float)21.5);
    tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.thirteen)));
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    b10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seek_bar.setEnabled(false);
    but19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
    but19.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void run() {
    int currentPosition= play.getCurrentPosition();
    int total = play.getDuration();
    while (play!=null && currentPosition<total) {
    try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    currentPosition= play.getCurrentPosition();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    return;
    }
    seek_bar.setProgress(currentPosition);
    }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(but19)) {
    if (play == null) {
    play = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ekadanta);
    seek_bar.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if (play.isPlaying()) {
    play.pause();
    but19.setText("Play");
    } else {
    play.start();
    but19.setText("Pause");
    seek_bar.setMax(play.getDuration());
    new Thread(this).start();
    }
    }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    if(play!=null){
    play.stop();
    }
    super.onPause();
    }

    public void increase(View inc) {
    count++;
    if (count == 1) {
    tv4.setTextSize(25);
    } else if (count == 2) {
    tv4.setTextSize(30);
    } else if (count >= 3) {
    count = 3;
    tv4.setTextSize(40);
    }
    }

    public void decrease(View dec) {
    count--;
    if (count <= 0) {
    tv4.setTextSize((float)21.5);
    count = 0;
    }
    if (count == 1) {
    tv4.setTextSize(25);
    } else if (count == 2) {
    tv4.setTextSize(30);
    } else if (count == 3) {
    tv4.setTextSize(40);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek_bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    try{
    if(play.isPlaying()||play!=null){
    if (fromUser)
    play.seekTo(progress);
    }
    else if(play==null){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First Play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    seek_bar.setProgress(0);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("seek bar",""+e);
    seek_bar.setEnabled(false);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
    }
```

Comment: try this http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/android-custom-notification-tutorial/

Comment: i want to pause the music for any incoming calls, when  the screen goes off and when the home button is pressed.... and should be able to play the music once back in the app....

Comment: Override `onStop` and `onStart` and inside `onStop` stop it if its playing and inside `onStart` play if its paused. Checkout on the docs when these methods are called. Checkout more here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Comment: Shobhit Puri....how it going to stop the music for the call....lockscreen.....homebutton??

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (play3!= null)
    {
        play3.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if ((play3 != null) && (!play3.isPlaying())) {
        but32.setText("Play");
        but32.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

This helped me to overcome my problems.....I'm able to play the music which gets paused when home button/lockscreen/calls appears...from where it had stopped